# The variable name '@' has already been declared & must declare scalar variable @

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I want to insert data from DataGridView to the database by using sqlparameters and for loop:

```
Dim sqlAddCmd As New SqlCommand

sqlAddCmd.CommandText =
                        "INSERT INTO TableName (Val,Idx,Ref,Sta,Col,Point,Mat,Refer,Cover,IDNo,Mas)" _
                            & "VALUES (@Val,@No,@Ref,@Sta,@Col,@Point,@Mat,@Refer,@Cover,@IDNo,@Mast)"

            sqlAddCmd.Transaction = transaction

            With sqlAddCmd.Parameters
                .Add("@Val", SqlDbType.Int)
                .Add("@No", SqlDbType.TinyInt)
                .Add("@Ref", SqlDbType.Char)
                .Add("@Sta", SqlDbType.Char)
                .Add("@Col", SqlDbType.VarChar)
                .Add("@Point", SqlDbType.SmallInt)
                .Add("@Mat", SqlDbType.VarChar)
                .Add("@Refer", SqlDbType.Int)
                .Add("@Cover", SqlDbType.TinyInt)
                .Add("@IDNo", SqlDbType.VarChar)
                .Add("@Mast", SqlDbType.Char)

            End With

            For intI = 0 To daGridView.Rows.Count
                With sqlAddCmd
                    .Parameters("@Val").Value = lngNewID
                    .Parameters("@No").Value = daGridView.Rows(intI).Cells("dgvNo").Value
                    .Parameters("@Ref").Value = daGridView.Rows(intI).Cells("dgvRef").Value
                    .Parameters("@Sta").Value = daGridView.Rows(intI).Cells("dgvSta").Value
                    .Parameters("@Col").Value = daGridView.Rows(intI).Cells("dgvCol").Value
                    .Parameters("@Point").Value = daGridView.Rows(intI).Cells("dgvPoint").Value
                    .Parameters("@Mat").Value = daGridView.Rows(intI).Cells("dgiMat").Value
                    .Parameters("@Refer").Value = daGridView.Rows(intI).Cells("dgiRefer").Value
                    .Parameters("@Cover").Value = daGridView.Rows(intI).Cells("dgiCover").Value
                    .Parameters("@IDNo").Value = daGridView.Rows(intI).Cells("dgiIDNo").Value
                    .Parameters("@Mast").Value = daGridView.Rows(intI).Cells("dgiMast").Value
                End With
                sqlAddCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Next
```

But when I want to insert this it will show the error code

> The Variable Name @Val has already been declared. Variable must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure.
> Must declare the scalar variable @No.

I know the val must be unique so I do that based on what the others suggest but still get the problem like this. Is there something missing?

Comment: Add has been deprecated because of possible ambiuguity - which is probably what is happening here. Use AddWithValue instead - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0

Comment: @CHill60, that is incorrect. The overload of `Add` being used is fine.

Comment: The problem here is presumably that you have executed this code twice for the same command object, so you're adding the same parameters multiple times. You haven't shown us how you create the command but you should be doing it where you use it, so you would create a new command object every time you execute that code.

Comment: isn't that problem that you try to do some batched parameter binding on a single VALUES insert. I'm no expect but you either need to execute one command each, or create separate parameters for every batch or use a table variable to insert data

Comment: You're doing it wrong in the first place though. You shouldn't be calling `ExecuteNonQuery` in a loop like that. You should create a `DataTable` and bind it to the grid. You can then save all the changes with a single call to `Update` on a suitable data adapter.

Comment: And probably it will not hurt anyone if you put all those column names inside square brackets. Just to avoid any possible problem with reserved keywords

Comment: `AddWithValue` is strongly recommended against (for SQL Server), @CHill60 . See [AddWithValue is Evil](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/). TL;DR: it infers the data types and that can cause all sorts of problems.

Comment: Consistency of naming is important. There seem to be some issues with parameter names, e.g.: `@Idx` in query but `@No` in parameters; `@Refer` in query but `@ReferTo` and `@Refer` in parameters; and so on...

Comment: I can see two issues in your parameters - The `@Idx`  and `@Refer` in your `INSERT` statement. In the Parameters you are using `@No` and `@ReferTo` and `@Refer`.

Comment: Where is `sqlAddCmd` coming from, where is it created? It shoud be in a `Using` so that it will be disposed, along with the connection and transaction objects. Side note: It's much faster to use `SqlBulkCopy` here.

Comment: `For intI = 0 To daGridView.Rows.Count` should be `For i = 0 To daGridView.Rows.Count - 1` - everyone knows that `i` is the usual name of the control variable in a for loop, and the last index is one less than the count.

Comment: Thank you for the responses and sorry for the late reply. Actually the `sqlAddCmd` is the SqlCommand I declare like `Dim sqlAddCmd As New SqlCommand`, but is this the right way?

Comment: have you tried to dispose the previous sqlCommand and SqlConnection? object may have been used prior to this, so that the variable `@Val` has already been declared.

Comment: I tried to create new sqlCommand and try to dispose / parameters.clear but cant fix the problem

Comment: @MrBim With parameters like `.Add("@Ref", SqlDbType.Char)`, it is best to specify the *size* of the column as declared in the database. For example, if in the database there was a column `Ref CHAR(20)` then you would use  `.Add("@Ref", SqlDbType.Char, 20)`.

Comment: @MrBim Have you put the column names (and the table name) in square brackets, as [suggested previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76752668/the-variable-name-has-already-been-declared-must-declare-scalar-variable#comment135313366_76752668) by user Steve? `INSERT INTO [TableName] ([Val], [Idx], [Ref], [Sta], [Col], [Point], [Mat], [Refer], [Cover], [IDNo], [Mas])`

Comment: @AndrewMorton actually I havent try what Steve suggest to me. I will try it first

Comment: @MrBim Also, I would convert the DGV values into the correct types, e.g., `.Parameters("@No").Value = CByte(daGridView.Rows(intI).Cells("dgvNo").Value)`. And is that a new instance of `transaction` being used?

Comment: @AndrewMorton yes the `transaction` is used before

Comment: it seems that transaction does have @val before.

Comment: you can comment out `sqlAddCmd.Transaction = transaction` line and execute the codes again. make sure to define your `sqlConnection`

Comment: Hi all I found to solve the problem. I create new Command like `sqlAddSomething` and instead using `For Loop` I use `Do While`. Then at the beginning of the loop I give `sqlAddSomething.parameters.clear()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer. The problem is I already use the `@Val` parameter. So I create new Parameter called `@ValDG`. And then instead of using `For ... Loop`,
I use `Do ... While`. So the code is like this:

```
intI = 0
Do While intI <= datagrid.Rows.Count - 1
sqlcommand.commandText = "INSERT INTO TableName (Val,Idx,Ref,Sta,Col,Point,Mat,Refer,Cover,IDNo,Mas)" _
                        & "VALUES (@ValDG,@No,@Ref,@Sta,@Col,@Point,@Mat,@Refer,@Cover,@IDNo,@Mast)"
sqlcommand.Transaction = transaction

With sqlcommand.parameters
    .Clear()
    .Add("@ValDG",SqlDbType.int).Value = lngNewID
    .....
End With
sqlcommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
intI +=1
Loop
```

I hope it will help. Sorry for the late answer post.